# spring restful web service validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

i am facing a problem, how to validate the null input in json?

here is my code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/findAdpId/", method=RequestMethod.POST , consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String findAdpId(@RequestBody AllCustomerHist customer){
        String customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
        String srctable = customer.getSrctable();
        String message;

        System.out.println("customer ID = "+customerId);
        System.out.println("srctable = "+srctable);

//      List<AllCustomerHist> adpcust = allCustomerHistService.findAdpId(customerId, srctable);
        BigDecimal adpcust = (BigDecimal) allCustomerHistService.findAdpId(customerId, srctable);


        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("adpId", adpcust);

        message = json.toString();
        return message;
    }
```

all i want is to validate `customerId` and `srctable` to be not null value, and here is my dto

```
@Entity
@Table(name="all_customer_hist")
public class AllCustomerHist {
    @Column(name = "REFF_FLAG")
    private String reffFlag;
    @Column(name = "REFF_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal reffId;
    @Column(name = "LAST_UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date lastUpdatedDate;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate;
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", length = 255)
    private String customerId;
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "DOB", length = 255)
    private String dob;
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_PLACE", length = 255)
    private String birthPlace;
    @Column(name = "GENDER", length = 255)
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "RELIGION", length = 255)
    private String religion;
    @Column(name = "EDUCATION", length = 255)
    private String education;
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_TYPE", length = 255)
    private String employeeType;
    @Column(name = "MARITAL_STATUS", length = 255)
    private String maritalStatus;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS", length = 300)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 255)
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "KECAMATAN", length = 255)
    private String kecamatan;
    @Column(name = "KELURAHAN", length = 255)
    private String kelurahan;
    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE", length = 255)
    private String zipCode;
    @Column(name = "BPS_CODE", length = 255)
    private String bpsCode;
    @Column(name = "ID_TYPE", length = 255)
    private String idType;
    @Column(name = "ID_NUMBER", length = 255)
    private String idNumber;
    @Column(name = "NPWP", length = 255)
    private String npwp;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String homePhone1;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String homePhone2;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String homePhone3;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String homePhone4;
    @Column(name = "HOME_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String homePhone5;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String officePhone1;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String officePhone2;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String officePhone3;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String officePhone4;
    @Column(name = "OFFICE_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String officePhone5;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_1", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone1;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_2", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone2;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_3", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone3;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_4", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone4;
    @Column(name = "MOBILE_PHONE_5", length = 255)
    private String mobilePhone5;
    @Column(name = "FAX_NUMBER_1", length = 255)
    private String faxNumber1;
    @Column(name = "FAX_NUMBER_2", length = 255)
    private String faxNumber2;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_1", length = 255)
    private String email1;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_2", length = 255)
    private String email2;
    @Column(name = "EMAIL_3", length = 255)
    private String email3;
    @Column(name = "SRCTABLE", length = 255)
    private String srctable;
    @Column(name = "ADP_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal adpId;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_entity_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="my_entity_seq_gen", sequenceName="SYSTEMID")
    @Column(name = "SYSTEM_ID", precision = 19, scale = 0)
    private BigDecimal systemId;

    //Release 1.2
    @Column(name = "NAME_RAW", length = 255)
    private String nameRaw;
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_TITLE", length = 8)
    private String customerTitle;
    @Column(name = "GENDERTITLE", length = 8)
    private String gendertitle;





    public String getNameRaw() {
        return nameRaw;
    }


    public void setNameRaw(String nameRaw) {
        this.nameRaw = nameRaw;
    }


    public String getCustomerTitle() {
        return customerTitle;
    }


    public void setCustomerTitle(String customerTitle) {
        this.customerTitle = customerTitle;
    }


    public String getGendertitle() {
        return gendertitle;
    }


    public void setGendertitle(String gendertitle) {
        this.gendertitle = gendertitle;
    }


    public String getReffFlag() {
        return reffFlag;
    }


    public void setReffFlag(String reffFlag) {
        this.reffFlag = reffFlag;
    }


    public BigDecimal getReffId() {
        return reffId;
    }


    public void setReffId(BigDecimal reffId) {
        this.reffId = reffId;
    }


    public Date getLastUpdatedDate() {
        return lastUpdatedDate;
    }


    public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) {
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
    }


    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }


    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }


    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }


    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }


    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    public String getBirthPlace() {
        return birthPlace;
    }


    public void setBirthPlace(String birthPlace) {
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
    }


    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }


    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }


    public String getReligion() {
        return religion;
    }


    public void setReligion(String religion) {
        this.religion = religion;
    }


    public String getEducation() {
        return education;
    }


    public void setEducation(String education) {
        this.education = education;
    }


    public String getEmployeeType() {
        return employeeType;
    }


    public void setEmployeeType(String employeeType) {
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
    }


    public String getMaritalStatus() {
        return maritalStatus;
    }


    public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }


    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public String getKecamatan() {
        return kecamatan;
    }


    public void setKecamatan(String kecamatan) {
        this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
    }


    public String getKelurahan() {
        return kelurahan;
    }


    public void setKelurahan(String kelurahan) {
        this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
    }


    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }


    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }


    public String getBpsCode() {
        return bpsCode;
    }


    public void setBpsCode(String bpsCode) {
        this.bpsCode = bpsCode;
    }


    public String getIdType() {
        return idType;
    }


    public void setIdType(String idType) {
        this.idType = idType;
    }


    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }


    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }


    public String getNpwp() {
        return npwp;
    }


    public void setNpwp(String npwp) {
        this.npwp = npwp;
    }


    public String getHomePhone1() {
        return homePhone1;
    }


    public void setHomePhone1(String homePhone1) {
        this.homePhone1 = homePhone1;
    }


    public String getHomePhone2() {
        return homePhone2;
    }


    public void setHomePhone2(String homePhone2) {
        this.homePhone2 = homePhone2;
    }


    public String getHomePhone3() {
        return homePhone3;
    }


    public void setHomePhone3(String homePhone3) {
        this.homePhone3 = homePhone3;
    }


    public String getHomePhone4() {
        return homePhone4;
    }


    public void setHomePhone4(String homePhone4) {
        this.homePhone4 = homePhone4;
    }


    public String getHomePhone5() {
        return homePhone5;
    }


    public void setHomePhone5(String homePhone5) {
        this.homePhone5 = homePhone5;
    }


    public String getOfficePhone1() {
        return officePhone1;
    }


    public void setOfficePhone1(String officePhone1) {
        this.officePhone1 = officePhone1;
    }


    public String getOfficePhone2() {
        return officePhone2;
    }


    public void setOfficePhone2(String officePhone2) {
        this.officePhone2 = officePhone2;
    }


    public String getOfficePhone3() {
        return officePhone3;
    }


    public void setOfficePhone3(String officePhone3) {
        this.officePhone3 = officePhone3;
    }


    public String getOfficePhone4() {
        return officePhone4;
    }


    public void setOfficePhone4(String officePhone4) {
        this.officePhone4 = officePhone4;
    }


    public String getOfficePhone5() {
        return officePhone5;
    }


    public void setOfficePhone5(String officePhone5) {
        this.officePhone5 = officePhone5;
    }


    public String getMobilePhone1() {
        return mobilePhone1;
    }


    public void setMobilePhone1(String mobilePhone1) {
        this.mobilePhone1 = mobilePhone1;
    }


    public String getMobilePhone2() {
        return mobilePhone2;
    }


    public void setMobilePhone2(String mobilePhone2) {
        this.mobilePhone2 = mobilePhone2;
    }


    public String getMobilePhone3() {
        return mobilePhone3;
    }


    public void setMobilePhone3(String mobilePhone3) {
        this.mobilePhone3 = mobilePhone3;
    }


    public String getMobilePhone4() {
        return mobilePhone4;
    }


    public void setMobilePhone4(String mobilePhone4) {
        this.mobilePhone4 = mobilePhone4;
    }


    public String getMobilePhone5() {
        return mobilePhone5;
    }


    public void setMobilePhone5(String mobilePhone5) {
        this.mobilePhone5 = mobilePhone5;
    }


    public String getFaxNumber1() {
        return faxNumber1;
    }


    public void setFaxNumber1(String faxNumber1) {
        this.faxNumber1 = faxNumber1;
    }


    public String getFaxNumber2() {
        return faxNumber2;
    }


    public void setFaxNumber2(String faxNumber2) {
        this.faxNumber2 = faxNumber2;
    }


    public String getEmail1() {
        return email1;
    }


    public void setEmail1(String email1) {
        this.email1 = email1;
    }


    public String getEmail2() {
        return email2;
    }


    public void setEmail2(String email2) {
        this.email2 = email2;
    }


    public String getEmail3() {
        return email3;
    }


    public void setEmail3(String email3) {
        this.email3 = email3;
    }


    public String getSrctable() {
        return srctable;
    }


    public void setSrctable(String srctable) {
        this.srctable = srctable;
    }


    public BigDecimal getAdpId() {
        return adpId;
    }


    public void setAdpId(BigDecimal adpId) {
        this.adpId = adpId;
    }


    public BigDecimal getSystemId() {
        return systemId;
    }


    public void setSystemId(BigDecimal systemId) {
        this.systemId = systemId;
    }

    public AllCustomerHist(){}

    public AllCustomerHist(String reffFlag, BigDecimal reffId, Date lastUpdatedDate, Date createdDate,
            String customerId, String name, String dob, String birthPlace, String gender, String religion,
            String education, String employeeType, String maritalStatus, String address, String city, String kecamatan,
            String kelurahan, String zipCode, String bpsCode, String idType, String idNumber, String npwp,
            String homePhone1, String homePhone2, String homePhone3, String homePhone4, String homePhone5,
            String officePhone1, String officePhone2, String officePhone3, String officePhone4, String officePhone5,
            String mobilePhone1, String mobilePhone2, String mobilePhone3, String mobilePhone4, String mobilePhone5,
            String faxNumber1, String faxNumber2, String email1, String email2, String email3, String srctable,
            BigDecimal adpId, BigDecimal systemId, String nameRaw, String customerTitle, String gendertitle) {
        super();
        this.reffFlag = reffFlag;
        this.reffId = reffId;
        this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.birthPlace = birthPlace;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.religion = religion;
        this.education = education;
        this.employeeType = employeeType;
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.kecamatan = kecamatan;
        this.kelurahan = kelurahan;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.bpsCode = bpsCode;
        this.idType = idType;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.npwp = npwp;
        this.homePhone1 = homePhone1;
        this.homePhone2 = homePhone2;
        this.homePhone3 = homePhone3;
        this.homePhone4 = homePhone4;
        this.homePhone5 = homePhone5;
        this.officePhone1 = officePhone1;
        this.officePhone2 = officePhone2;
        this.officePhone3 = officePhone3;
        this.officePhone4 = officePhone4;
        this.officePhone5 = officePhone5;
        this.mobilePhone1 = mobilePhone1;
        this.mobilePhone2 = mobilePhone2;
        this.mobilePhone3 = mobilePhone3;
        this.mobilePhone4 = mobilePhone4;
        this.mobilePhone5 = mobilePhone5;
        this.faxNumber1 = faxNumber1;
        this.faxNumber2 = faxNumber2;
        this.email1 = email1;
        this.email2 = email2;
        this.email3 = email3;
        this.srctable = srctable;
        this.adpId = adpId;
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.nameRaw = nameRaw;
        this.customerTitle = customerTitle;
        this.gendertitle = gendertitle;
    }
}
```

my goal is, when this json thrown:

```
{
    "srctable":null,
    "customerId":null
    }
```

it should returned message, informed the consumer that srctable and customerId cannot be null, but i dont want to add @NotNull in my dto since customerId and srctable might be null for other process.

thank you, awaiting your helps :D

Comment: You can always use an `if-else` condition in such cases!

Comment: 1. Your pasted code contains too much data - you don't need entire AllCustomerHist class to illustrate your problem. 2. Binding your DB model to API model is almost always a very BAD choice. 3. The thing you want is actually a Domain level validation, and it should not be performed inside controller.

Comment: @RafalG. actually i have model layer, dao layer, and service layer, i dont really get it with  "Binding your DB model to API model is almost always a very BAD choice" can you explain it more detail about it?

and also wwhat is domain level validation? and where it should be performed? since the request is processed from controller

Answer (score 1):

It's time to introduce DTO (Data Transfer Object) and use it in the controller. Guess you don't need some of the fields e.g. lastUpdatedDate of the entity is not used in the search logic.

You need to add a custom POJO with necessary fields and annotate it with @NotNull and all other necessary validation checks. You may need a converter as well to convert the DTO to Entity when necessary.

Comment: yes, not all of the fields needed for this method, should i create new dto?

i dont really get it for the part adding custom pojo with necessary fields and annotate it with @NotNull and all other necessary validation checks. You may need a converter as well to convert the DTO to Entity when necessary.

can you explain it more detail about it? thank you

Comment: Yes. Benefits - less info to pass, split model (entity) and Controller (DTO), any validation you need (additionally converted could include e.g. transformation from string representation to classes. E.g. for Date field I can pass values "now" or "yesterday" and add binding logic to convert to Date class).

Comment: do you have any good reference about that? i'm quite new in spring in java

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application check this one

Comment: Hi, i already have entity, dao, and service layer, is it okay to add dto layer without modifying dao & entity layer? do i only need to modify rest controller using object mapper for dto?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Valid` from `javax.validation.Valid` with `@NotNull` annotation.

Also, I would like to suggest one blog for rest API validation [here](https://lmonkiewicz.com/programming/get-noticed-2017/spring-boot-rest-request-validation/).

Comment: i dont want to use @Notnull anotation in my entity object, because not all the process requires the fields is null/not null

anyway thanks for sharing :)